# Testing XML with FitNesse Automation Framework

Tags: fitnesse

We have the scenario to pass the XML file as input to the applications and validate the schema and transactions, Is there any FitNesse fixture framework available to simulate this?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a pre-defined fixture available but you can write your own, e.g., based on Do Fixture, something like:

```
|myXmlFixture|
|set schema file|xxx|
|validate xml file|yyy|
```